# Vuejs SPA / Gunicorn Nginx / index.html cache

Tags: nginx, caching

All my javascript/css stuff gets versioned when run to production so when a new release is out the files are different on the index.html file which should force a reload of the files.

However the index.html file is getting cached. I am not sure how to allow caching of all of the js and css without allowing the index.html file to cache.

I can ad the no caching headers to the index file but that stops caching on everything i just want index.html to be served fresh evertime to the users browser so they can can detrimine if they need to request new js files for instance.

I no having it not caching anything but this is a broken way to handle this.

What happens if i don't do that is that nginx seems to give them stale versions of index.html.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you try to "not-cache" index.html only using below nginx configuration?

```
location = /index.html {
  expires -1;
}
```